# TCL list data to histogram

Tags: arrays, tcl, histogram

I'm doing some data analysis, and the output is a long list of numbers.  Each line consists of 1 to n numbers, which may be duplicated:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 4
```

I'd like to put these into a (time-series) histogram.  I'm not an expert in tcl (yet?), and I have some ideas how to do this but I have not been successful yet.  The puts statements are just so I can see what's happening.

---

```
while { [gets $infile line] != -1 } {
    set m [llength $line]
    puts "line length $m"
    foreach item $line {
        puts $item
        incr nc($item)
        puts "nc: $nc($item)"
    }
}
```

this nc array I've created *is* giving me a size-based array.  However, I'd like a per-line based array (2D).  Naively it would be nc($item)($nlines).  I initially tried labeling the array variable with the length such as nc${item}($nlines), but I am not smart enough to get that to work.

I appreciate any help.
Best
Mike

Comment: Show the output you want to see. Tcl arrays are strictly one-dimensional. You can use `dict` to make a dictionary-of-dictionaries

Comment: I'm not sure where the information about the `nlines` come from, with your question as it is right now, if `nlines` is different from the size of the `item`.

Comment: Glenn, The (not really output at this point) would be nc1(1) = 20, nc2(1) = 8, nc3(1) = 2, nc4(1) = 1, where the array index is the line number of the original data file.  This was one of the things i tried: nc${item}($lineno) or some such but my output was the variable name itself rather than the value..  Thanks!

Comment: Jerry, in my example, `nlines` is the length of the file being read.  Your comment looks incomplete to me. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful treating the **string** $line as a **list** -- if it contains unbalanced braces, you'll get an error. Take care to convert between strings and lists with `split` and `join` -- you should have `set m [llength [split $line]]` and `foreach item [split $line] {}`

Answer (score 0):

Although Tcl arrays are one-dimensional, you can construct key strings to fake multi-dimensionality:

```
set lineno -1
set fh [open infile r]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    incr lineno
    foreach item [split [string trim $line]] {
        incr nc($lineno,$item)
    }
}
close $fh

# `parray` is a handy command for inspecting arrays
parray nc
```

outputs

```
nc(0,1) = 20
nc(0,2) = 8
nc(0,3) = 2
nc(0,4) = 1
nc(1,1) = 2
nc(1,2) = 4
nc(1,4) = 3
nc(2,1) = 1
nc(2,2) = 1
nc(2,3) = 1
nc(2,4) = 1
```

Or use dictionaries:

```
set lineno -1
set nc {}
set fh [open infile r]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    set thisLine {}
    foreach item [split [string trim $line]] {
        dict incr thisLine $item
    }
    dict set nc [incr lineno] $thisLine
}
close $fh

dict for {line data} $nc {
    puts [list $line $data]
}
```

outputs

```
0 {1 20 2 8 3 2 4 1}
1 {1 2 2 4 4 3}
2 {1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1}
```

Comment: Hi Glenn!  OK, I think that (first example) worked.  The `parray` command did spit out the contents, though in somewhat random order (which shouldn't matter as I can control the indices as in a normal array, I would gather?).  I guess I need to examine the `split` and join commands.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: It's actually the exact opposite of "random order" -- it's sorted lexically. See https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/artifact/a0b1bd4e68dce176